# R Error Message

Tags: r

I'm trying to read in a text file (.txt) in R and I'm continually getting this error message:

```
tab1=read.table("./leg_table.txt",h=T)
Error in read.table("./leg_table.txt", h = T) :
  more columns than column name
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It tells you that you have more columns than column name. Or less column names than columns.

Comment: or you have data with spaces and the strings are unquoted

Comment: FYI it is not good practice to use `h=T` instead of `h=TRUE`

Comment: @RockScience I actually prefer `header=TRUE` for complete readability.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen agreed, although that's more for convenience than for robustness. Avoiding `T` is important for robustness as if you run the same code with a `T` loaded, it will break it. Try for instance `T=FALSE` then run the code above. or `T=matrix(NA,2,2)`

Comment: did you know that @TimBiegeleisen :}

Comment: @rawr Yes because I think you pointed this out to me a few months ago.  I always write out `TRUE` explicitly now :-)

Answer (score 1):

This error is pretty self-explanatory, but here is an example of an input text file which would cause this error:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
1    2    3    4
2    3    4    5
3    4    5    6
```

You have `N` column headers, but one or more rows of the data (beginning on line 2) has *more* than `N` columns.

If you post say the first 10 rows of `leg_table.txt` we will know for certain what the problem is.